# What madness is preventing access to my smoothieboard web server?

Tags: networking, apache2

I've been installing stuff on a new ubuntu 20.04 computer to run my 3D printer. I have a crossover cable between the smoothieboard in my printer and an ethernet connector on my ubuntu system. I've configured the ethernet to manually be 192.168.2.1/24 and configured the smoothie to manually connect to 192.168.2.2/24 with 192.168.2.1 as a gateway. For some wild and crazy reason, if I go to 192.168.2.2 in firefox, I get an apache2 success screen. I know the smoothieboard doesn't have a copy of apache2 on it. If I telnet to 192.168.2.2 I do indeed get a smoothieboard telnet prompt. What lunatic setting is redirecting my web access attempt back to the local system? Is this some haproxy insanity from installing OctoPrint?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I ran google-chrome instead of firefox, and it talked to the smoothieboard just fine. Dug through firefox settings and turned off proxy, but that didn't help even after a restart. Only after I flushed every bit of cache and history would firefox see the smoothieboard. Sheesh.